# Convert an expression with complex exponentials to a function using lambdify in Sympy

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I have a Sympy expression of the form

```
exp =  0.5*y1**2 + 2*y1*y2 + 2.5*x5**2 + 5.0*x6**2 - 25.0*exp(2.0*I*x4)*exp(1.0*I*x5) - 25.0*exp(2.0*I*x4) + 100.0 - 25.0*exp(-2.0*I*x4) - 25.0*exp(-2.0*I*x4)*exp(-1.0*I*x5)
```

I would like to convert the above expression to a function using the variables as arguments. Further, the parameters take sparse scipy csc matrices as input in place of the variables. So, I used the following to convert it into a function.

```
func = lambdify((y1,y2,x4,x5,x6),exp,"scipy")
```

Though, this function is generated without any error the function does not work with csc sparse matrices. It gives the following error:

```
from scipy import sparse
a = sparse.identity(12000,format="csc")
func(a,a,a,a,a) # just to test the output
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    686         else:
--> 687             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    688 

AttributeError: exp not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-321-ee4555e1ca2e> in <module>
      1 a = sparse.identity(21,format="csc")
----> 2 func(a,a)

<lambdifygenerated-23> in _lambdifygenerated(x2, n2)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(x2, n2):
----> 2     return (0.125*n2**2 - 25.0*exp(2.0*1j*x2) - 25.0*exp(-2.0*1j*x2))

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/_lib/deprecation.py in call(*args, **kwargs)
     18             warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning,
     19                           stacklevel=stacklevel)
---> 20             return fun(*args, **kwargs)
     21         call.__doc__ = msg
     22         return call

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type csc_matrix which has no callable exp method
```

Which shows that the exponent of a sparse matrix is not defined. So, I tried to replace the exp(I*x1) with a separate variable and then use that as a parameter. But, when I use subs, I get the following result.

```
$exp.subs(exp(I*x4),e4)
0.5*y1**2 + 2*y1*y2 + 2.5*x5**2 + 5.0*x6**2 - 25.0*e4**2.0*exp(1.0*I*x5) - 25.0*e4**2.0 + 100.0 - 25.0/e4**2.0 - 25.0/e4**2.0*exp(-1.0*I*x5)
```

The problem with the above result is that the negative powers of the exponential are replaced with variable e4 in the denominator. So, a lambdify version of the same does not work with matrices as the operation of division for a matrix is undefined. I tried to use replace to replace the terms of the form `exp(1.0*I*x5)` and `exp(-1.0*I*x5)` separately, but this does not work well with terms such as `exp(2.0*I*x5)`.

Can anything be done to work around this situation? Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Some part of the above answer is modified to include a reproducible example. Also, I am using square matrices with complex numbers, whose size can be much larger, like 12000 x 12000.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see you creating sparse matrices or using them in the function!  [mcve]

Comment: What's the `shape` of the arguments, whether sparse, dense or scalar?

Comment: I have added an example to make it more reproducible. Also, the shape of the arguments are all the same but can be very large, in some instances have a shape greater than 12000x12000.

Answer (score 1):

`np.exp` cannot work on a sparse matrix:

```
In [64]: from scipy import sparse
In [65]: M = sparse.random(10,10,.2, 'csc')
In [66]: np.exp(M)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 687, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: exp not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-66-1b6c717c2aff>", line 1, in <module>
    np.exp(M)
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type csc_matrix which has no callable exp method
```

`np.exp`, like many `numpy` functions, turns non-array arguments into arrays first:

```
In [67]: np.array(M)
Out[67]: 
array(<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>, dtype=object)
```

But that naive conversion just produces a 0d object dtpe array, without changing the sparse matrix.  In turn it tries to use a non-existent `exp` method.

Properly converting the sparse matrix to a (dense) array does work:

```
np.exp(M.A)
```

producing an array result.  You don't loose anything by switching to dense arrays, since `exp(0)` is 1.

Use `help(f)` (or ipython `f?`) to see the function's doc (and code), e.g.:

```
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x, y)

Expression:

0.5*x**2 + 25.0*exp(2*I*x)

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
    return (0.5*x**2 + 25.0*exp(2*1j*x))
```

`np.expm1(M)` also works, because `M.expm1()` is defined.

Since `exp(0)` is 1, doing `exp` on a sparse matrix would produce an array with 1's where the original had 0s, i.e. a non-sparse array.  `expm1` on the other hand preserves sparsity, in effect it can apply the function to all non-zero elements, ignoring the (default) 0s.

In sum, change your `x4` and `x5` to dense arrays, and it should run.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But, wouldn't changing the sparse to dense matrices affect the performance for very large matrices, like in my case? Also, I have tried using the function np.expm1, but it seems that cannot be used to define to define an exponential of a symbol in sympy expression.

Comment: The translation from sympy to numpy is straight forward.  So you could easily write the numpy from scatch.  But I don't know enough about your sparse matrices to say whether its worth trying to preserve them or not. My key point is that the exp of a sparse matrix is no longer sparse.

Comment: Even if all the arguments are sparse (and same sparsity), due to the exp terms the result will not be sparse.  So I doubt if using sparse is saving you any time.

Comment: Okay, I have been able to use the expm1 Numpy function in lambdify, by modifying its globals dictionary. `f = lambdify((symbols("v2,x2")),exp.expand(), [{'exp':np.expm1},"numpy"]) ` . This seems to work with sparse matrices, and also preserves the sparsity. This should work right? I hope I am not missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by editing the globals dictionary used by the lambdify function. This function describes the functions which replace the mathematical functions used in a sympy expression. Since the problem here is with the operator of `exp`, it can be replaced by `expm` from scipy using the following command. The resultant function is now able to take csc sparse matrices as input.

```
f = lambdify((symbols("v2,x2")),exp.expand(), [{'exp':scipy.linalg.expm},"scipy"])
```

Hope this helps anyone else facing a similar problem!

Comment: Using `expm1` directly in place of `exp` is not right because it calculates `exp(x)-1` rather than `exp(x)`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, yes that seems to be the case. Then would it be okay to use scipy.linalg.expm? Would this be an efficient method to compute the expression I need for very large sparse matrices?